# Is it possible to control interface rendering using JAAS?

Tags: authentication, authorization, seam, roles, jaas

I need something to do a role based permission when rendering elements on a page exactly like implemented in JBoss Seam where you have the `rendered` tag while declaring the page elements. My doubt is if it is possible to do that using standard JAAS?

The container(weblogic) is connected to the LDAP server where the user is associated with a bunch of groups/roles and I would like to use some declarative approach to render menu elements based on the groups the user logged in belongs. That would be exactly like the Roles/rendered implemented in JBoss Seam 2. Is it possible to do that or something similar with standard J2EE? If not, Is there some Open Source API who would do the job?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some days of research what I did was configured weblogic realm to connect to the LDAP and than using a standard form login:

```
<form method="POST" action="j_security_check">
<p>Username: <input type="text" name="j_username"/></p>
<p>Password: <input type="password" name="j_password"/></p>
<input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

After that I had my interface rendering using:

```
if(request.isUserInRole("ROLE_NAME"));
```

to check if the logged in user should be presented with a specific interface fragment. It worked.